# webpage deployed on heroku shows blank background unless F5 refresh the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask, bootstrap-4

I am doing a group chat program using Python microframework `flask`, `vanilla JavaScript` and `Flask-SocketIO`. I already deployed it on `heroku`: https://chat-ya.herokuapp.com/.

However, the question is:

it works fine on local machine before I deployed it. But when I deployed it, open the website, the background image is

1. not showing, or
2. sometimes only part of it is showing, or
3. sometimes just flickers and becomes blank

I have tried to optimize the image's size, but still not working.

the data structure tree is:

```
 static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── index.css(main page css)
│   │   ├── channel.css(channel page css)
│   │   ├── bootstrap.min.cs
│   │   └── all.css
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── aircraft.jpeg
│   │   ├── ....
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── index.js(main page js)
│   │   ├── channel.js(channel page js)
│   │   ├── bootstrap.bundle.min.js
│   │   ├── jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js
│   │   └── socket.io.js
│   ├── music
│       └── GrandmaSaid.mp3
└── templates
    ├── base.html
    ├── channel.html(channel page)
    └── index.html(main page, extended from base.html)
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

That's really an unfixable error - it has to do with the time between the browser loading the page and saying, *Hey, can you get this image for me?* and the server going *I'll look for it - OK, found it, here you go!*  And of course, it'll be impacted if multiple people are on the page as well. So unless you find a faster web server, it's not really capable of loading faster. And you and Bootstrap may have some conflicting rules in CSS which mean that your image is partially cut off.

Ask me if you need any help with this!